# NPE when using DI with Spring in JAX-WS project

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jax-ws, javabeans

I am working on a JAX-WS project, and now I would like to add dependency injection for one of my utilities.

The utility has an interface; GeocodeUtil, and two implementations, GeocodeUtilGoogleImpl and GeocodeUtilYahooImpl. Now, in my service class I have the following:

```
public class MyService {
    private GeocodeUtil geocodeUtil;
    /* getter and setter for geocodeUtil */
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have the following:

```
<bean id="geocodeUtil" class="com.company.GeocodeUtilGoogleImpl"/>
<bean id="myService" class="com.company.MyService">
    <property name="geocodeUtil" ref="geocodeUtil" />
</bean>
```

Heres my web.xml (only the part related to Spring):

```
<!-- Spring context -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Listeners -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When I create an instance of the MyService object, and try to use the geocodeUtil, I get a NullPointerException and it seems to me that the implementation wasn't injected. 
What I think is strange is that as soon as I remove the getter/setter, the application crashes on launch and Spring complains about the missing setter/getter which leads me to think that the XML-configuration is in fact correct.

I am not using any spring-related Java-annotations.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While its not clear from you post, I suspect your not retrieving the instance from the application context. If you aren't using any annotations then the code that calls the your MyService object needs to fetch the bean from the application context by doing something like this :

```
ServletContext servletContext =this.getServletContext();

 WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.
getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

 MyService user = (MyService)wac.getBean("myService");
```

The spring configuration you've provided is correct. All you need to do is make sure the applicaiton context is created, and that you are retrievign your object from the applicaiton context. See here for more info:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-client

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. From what I gather from your answer I can avoid having to get the bean via the AppContext with annotations? I've only used Spring with Wicket projects before, and in these projects I could use an annotation named "@SpringBean". Is there an equivalent of this annotation for plain Spring?

Comment: You can use @Autowired to wire up the Services or @Resource. There are pluses and minuses to both annotations. Take a look at the spring docs. However, you have to configure you web to inject dependencies, which means  you have to add soemthing like this :  <context:annotation-config/>
to your application context (see : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) there will probably be some other configuration that you have to do because you aren't using spring-mvc.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the Service instance from the Spring context as well.

Creating a service object with new operator will not trigger spring to inject objects for that instance.